# How do I use cache_clear() on python @functools.lru_cache

Tags: python, python-3.x

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) states:

> The decorator also provides a `cache_clear()` function for clearing or
>   invalidating the cache.

It doesn't provide any examples or guidance on how to use `cache_clear()`

I have two questions:

- How can I run `cache_clear()` from a different function?
- If I put a `cache_clear()` call conditionally inside the function that is being cached, will it ever get executed?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Besides caching, `lru_cache` decorator also adds new functions, to the decorated function - `cache_info` and `cache_clear`. Below is a simple example that should explain how they work:

```
>>> @lru_cache(5)
... def foo():
...     print('Executing foo...')
... 
>>> foo()
Executing foo...
>>> foo()
>>> foo.cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=1, maxsize=5, currsize=1)
>>> foo.cache_clear()
>>> foo()
Executing foo...
```

Answering your questions:

> If I put a cache_clear() call conditionally inside the function that is being cached, will it ever get executed?

If the result is not cached already, the function will execute and based on your conditions, it should execute `cache_clear`. I wouldn't use such solution though - a good practise is to invalidate outside the cached object, otherwise you risk no invalidation at all in worst cases, unreadable code in best case.

> How can I run cache_clear() from a different function?

Just import cached function and call `cache_clear` on it:

```
from x import foo

def bar():
    foo.cache_clear()
```

Answer (score 22):

If the method you are trying to expire the cache for is a property:

```
class Foo:
    @property
    @lru_cache()
    def bar(self):
       return 42
```

Then you can clear the cache this way:

```
Foo.bar.fget.cache_clear()
```

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55497384/8953378

Answer (score 0):

If the method is decorated by custom functions, like:

```py
Class myclass
    @dec1
    @dec2
    ...
    @decX
    @lru_cache()
    def myfunc()
```

its also possible to access the `lru_cache` wrapper by accessing the `__dict__` and then the `__wrapped__` key in it, as many times as needed, like this:

```py
myclass.myfunc.__dict__["__wrapped__"].__dict__["__wrapped__"].....__dict__["__wrapped__"]cache_clear()
```