# Python: recall cached function result dependent on new function parameter

Tags: python-3.x, caching, memoization

I am fairly new to the concepts of caching & memoization.  I've read some other discussions & resources [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815110/is-there-a-decorator-to-simply-cache-function-return-values), [here](https://github.com/0k/kids.cache), and [here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache), but haven't been able to follow them all that well.

Say that I have two member functions within a class.  (Simplified example below.)  Pretend that the first function `total` is computationally expensive.  The second function `subtotal` is computationally simple, except that it uses the return from the first function, and so also becomes computationally expensive because of this, in that it currently needs to re-call `total` to get its returned result.

I want to cache the results of the first function and use this as the input to the second, *if* the input `y` to `subtotal` shares the input `x` to a recent call of `total`.  That is:

- If calling subtotal() where `y` is equal to the value of `x` in a
  previous call of `total`, then use that cached result instead of
  re-calling `total`.
- Otherwise, just call `total()` using `x = y`.

Example:

```
class MyObject(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b

    def total(self, x):
        return (self.a + self.b) * x     # some time-expensive calculation

    def subtotal(self, y, z):
        return self.total(x=y) + z       # Don't want to have to re-run total() here
                                         # IF y == x from a recent call of total(),
                                         # otherwise, call total().
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18723434/2570677. I've used it in my code and it works perfectly.

Comment: Assuming you're referring to `@functools.lru_cache`?

Comment: from the resources you link to, what is stopping you from just decorating `total` with a basic cache feature? you'd just put `@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=N)` and it'd cache `N` results for the same arguments. Why is that not going to work in your scenario?

Comment: @BradSolomon I'm referring to the answer containing the implementation (without any external module). It works in python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the responses, it was helpful just to read them and see what's going on under the hood.  As @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen said, it seems like I didn't need anything more here than `@functools.lru_cache`.  (I'm in Python 3.5.)  Regarding @unutbu's comment, I'm not getting an error from decorating total() with `@lru_cache`.  Let me correct my own example, I'll keep this up here for other beginners:

```
from functools import lru_cache
from datetime import datetime as dt

class MyObject(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b

    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def total(self, x):        
        lst = []
        for i in range(int(1e7)):
            val = self.a + self.b + x    # time-expensive loop
            lst.append(val)
        return np.array(lst)     

    def subtotal(self, y, z):
        return self.total(x=y) + z       # if y==x from a previous call of
                                         # total(), used cached result.

myobj = MyObject(1, 2)

# Call total() with x=20
a = dt.now()
myobj.total(x=20)
b = dt.now()
c = (b - a).total_seconds()

# Call subtotal() with y=21
a2 = dt.now()
myobj.subtotal(y=21, z=1)
b2 = dt.now()
c2 = (b2 - a2).total_seconds()

# Call subtotal() with y=20 - should take substantially less time
# with x=20 used in previous call of total().
a3 = dt.now()
myobj.subtotal(y=20, z=1)
b3 = dt.now()
c3 = (b3 - a3).total_seconds()

print('c: {}, c2: {}, c3: {}'.format(c, c2, c3))
c: 2.469753, c2: 2.355764, c3: 0.016998
```

Comment: Do `self.a` and `self.b` ever change? If so, the cached value should be cleared since the computed value of `total` would change. You could implement that by making `a` and `b` settable properties whose setter calls [`total.cache_clear()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37654201/190597).

Comment: PS: I was wrong about applying lru_cache to a class method raising an error. Although there is no error, [it does cause a memory leak](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33672412/190597) however.

Comment: Here `self.a` and `self.b` won't be modified.  But thanks, that's helpful to know.

Answer (score 2):

With Python3.2 or newer, you could use `functools.lru_cache`. 
If you were to decorate the `total` with `functools.lru_cache` directly, then the `lru_cache` would cache the return values of `total` based on the value of both arguments, `self` and `x`. Since lru_cache's internal dict stores a reference to self, applying @lru_cache directly to a class method creates a circular reference to `self` which makes instances of the class un-dereferencable (hence a memory leak).

[Here is a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33672499/190597) which allows you to use `lru_cache` with class methods -- it caches results based on all arguments other than the first one, `self`, and uses a [weakref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) to avoid the circular reference problem:

```
import functools
import weakref

def memoized_method(*lru_args, **lru_kwargs):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/33672499/190597 (orly)
    """
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # We're storing the wrapped method inside the instance. If we had
            # a strong reference to self the instance would never die.
            self_weak = weakref.ref(self)
            @functools.wraps(func)
            @functools.lru_cache(*lru_args, **lru_kwargs)
            def cached_method(*args, **kwargs):
                return func(self_weak(), *args, **kwargs)
            setattr(self, func.__name__, cached_method)
            return cached_method(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_func
    return decorator


class MyObject(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b

    @memoized_method()
    def total(self, x):
        print('Calling total (x={})'.format(x))
        return (self.a + self.b) * x


    def subtotal(self, y, z):
        return self.total(x=y) + z 

mobj = MyObject(1,2)
mobj.subtotal(10, 20)
mobj.subtotal(10, 30)
```

prints

```
Calling total (x=10)
```

only once.

---

Alternatively, this is how you could roll your own cache using a dict:

```
class MyObject(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b
        self._total = dict()

    def total(self, x):
        print('Calling total (x={})'.format(x))
        self._total[x] = t = (self.a + self.b) * x
        return t

    def subtotal(self, y, z):
        t = self._total[y] if y in self._total else self.total(y)
        return t + z 

mobj = MyObject(1,2)
mobj.subtotal(10, 20)
mobj.subtotal(10, 30)
```

One advantage of `lru_cache` over this dict-based cache is that the `lru_cache`
is thread-safe. The `lru_cache` also has a `maxsize` parameter which can help
protect against memory usage growing without bound (for example, due to a
long-running process calling `total` many times with different values of `x`).

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would do something simple, maybe is not the most elegant way, but works for the problem:

```
class MyObject(object):
    param_values = {}
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b

    def total(self, x):
        if x not in MyObject.param_values:
          MyObject.param_values[x] = (self.a + self.b) * x
          print(str(x) + " was never called before")
        return MyObject.param_values[x]

    def subtotal(self, y, z):
        if y in MyObject.param_values:
          return MyObject.param_values[y] + z
        else:
          return self.total(y) + z
```