# Test function with lru_cache decorator

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, functools

I'm attempting to test a a method that is memoized through `lru_cache` (since it's an expensive database call). with `pytest-mock`.

A simplified version of the code is:

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, file):
        # load a file

    @lru_cache
    def get(self, user_id):
        # do expensive call
```

Then I'm testing:

```
class TestUser:

    def test_get_is_called(self, mocker):
        data = mocker.ANY
        user = User(data)
        repository.get(user_id)
        open_mock = mocker.patch('builtins.open', mocker.mock_open())
        open_mock.assert_called_with('/foo')
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: '_ANY'
```

This happens because `functools.lru_cache` needs the keys stored to be *hashable* i.e. have a method `__hash__` or `__cmp__` implemented.

How can I mock such methods in a mocker to make it work?

I've tried

```
user.__hash__.return_value = 'foo'
```

with no luck.

Comment: Please add a [MCVE].  The value of `repository`, and hence the impl of `repository.get`, is undefined here.

Comment: Although the particular example may be specific, tests alru-cached functions with pytest is a genuine problem, and the answer here is only for this specific case.

Comment: In case you are interested to clear the pytest cache in between testcases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72222314/python-clear-reset-lru-cache-functool-caching-with-every-pytest-testcase-f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `mocker.ANY` (an object which is intented to be used in assertions as a placeholder that's equal to any object) I believe you instead want to use a sentinel object (such as `mocker.sentinel.DATA`).

This appears to work from a quick test:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def f(x):
    return (x, x)


def test(mocker):
    ret = f(mocker.sentinel.DATA)
    assert ret == (mocker.sentinel.DATA, mocker.sentinel.DATA)
```

Answer (score 37):

For people arriving here trying to work out how to test functions decorated with `lru_cache` or `alru_cache`, the answer is to [clear the cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37654201/2071807) before each test.

This can be done as follows:

```
def setup_function():
    """
    Avoid the `(a)lru_cache` causing tests with identical parameters to interfere
    with one another.
    """
    my_cached_function.cache_clear()
```

Comment: Nice play to expectations!

Comment: This cleared up so many of my problems!

Answer (score 2):

## How to switch off `@lru_cache` when running pytest

In case you ended up here because you want to test an `@lru_cache` - decorated function with different mocking (but the lru_cache prevents your mocking) ...
Just set the `maxsize` of the `@lru_cache` to 0 if you run pytest!

```py
@lru_cache(maxsize=0 if "pytest" in sys.modules else 256)
```

### Minimal working example

with @lru_cache active (maxsize=256) when code runs and deactivated (maxsize=0) if pytest runs:

```
import sys
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=0 if "pytest" in sys.modules else 256)
def fct_parent():
    return fct_child()

def fct_child():
    return "unmocked"


def test_mock_lru_cache_internal(monkeypatch):
    """This test fails if @lru_cache of fct_parent is active and succeeds otherwise"""
    print(f"{fct_parent.cache_info().maxsize=}")
    for ii in range(2):
        ret_val = f"mocked {ii}"
        with monkeypatch.context() as mpc:
            mpc.setattr(f"{__name__}.fct_child", lambda: ret_val)  # mocks fct_child to return ret_val
            assert fct_parent() == ret_val

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """
    This module is designed to fail, if called by python
        $ python test_lru_cache_mocking.py
    and to work if exectued by pytest
        $ pytest -s test_lru_cache_mocking.py
    
    The reason is, that the size of the lru_cache is 256 / 0 respectively 
    and hence test_mock_lru_cache_internal fails / succeeds.
    """
    #
    from _pytest.monkeypatch import MonkeyPatch
    test_mock_lru_cache_internal(MonkeyPatch())
```

Comment: this is a bit more sophisticated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72222315/7128154