# getting `cache_info()` with cachetools

Tags: python, python-3.x, caching

I'm using [cachetools](https://cachetools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and I want to get the `cache_info()`:

```
class UserData(object):
    def __init__():
        ...

    @cached(cache=TTLCache(maxsize=1024, ttl=600))
    def get_user_data(self, user_id):
        return self.redis.get_user_data(user_id)

    def get_cache_info():
        return self.get_user_data.cache_info()
```

I want to get the cache statistics as appear in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653784/how-do-i-use-cache-clear-on-python-functools-lru-cache):

```
>>> foo.cache_info()
CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=1, maxsize=5, currsize=1)
```

I know that's a different cache (I'm using 3rd party library) but in the documentation above the  `cache_info` does exist. Is there a way to get the `TTLCache` statistics somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [code](https://github.com/tkem/cachetools/blob/1311be69d9e68199cc800123f7bc5c610dd720d6/cachetools/func.py#L166) and [documentation](https://github.com/tkem/cachetools/issues/131)  you should use `ttl_cache` from `func.py`:

```
from cachetools.func import ttl_cache


class UserData(object):
    ...
    @ttl_cache(maxsize=1024, ttl=600)
    def get_user_data(self, user_id):
        return self.redis.get_user_data(user_id)
```

You should then be able to call `UserData.get_user_data.cache_info()`.

`cached` decorator does not maintain any statistics.